# Visualising a DNA/state sequence over time

Tags: matlab

I have 400 sequences of discrete variables all varying in length, where zeros are simply place holders. For example:

```
X=[
    5   3   5   5   4   1   4   4   2
    5   4   4   3   3   4   5   2   4
    5   2   4   4   2   3   3   3   0
    2   3   3   3   0   0   0   0   0
    4   5   3   3   2   3   3   3   3
    3   2   4   2   3   3   5   0   0
    2   4   4   5   4   5   5   0   0
    4   2   5   5   0   0   0   0   0
   ]
```

How could I visualise these changing sequences over time in a single graph or animation?
A stair graph looks nice but I can't put 400 sequences all on one graph it would be cluttered. [image]

A bar graph of a histogram of the most likely state at each time step looks like this but it's not very intuitive:

```
[f x]=hist(X6,0:1:5);
bar3c(f)
```

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: What information should be visible in the final graph?

Comment: I would like to show the change in time of the sequences, perhaps on average. Also it black and white or grey-scale if possible.  Someone suggested this http://www.gapminder.org/videos/ Gapminder type plot which is interesting...

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple image:

```
X = X+1; %Because otherwise your zeros and ones come out as the same colour for some weird reason I don't understand

I = uint8(X./max(X(:))*255);
image(I);
colormap(autumn(256));  %// or grey(256) for b&w
colorbar;
```

or else maybe

```
bar3(X)
```